# VB Excel, Count Shapes with same color

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How could I get the total number of shapes I have in an excel sheet with same color? For eg, I have 3 red color shapes, 2 green color shapes, and 1 yellow color shape and I wish to get the result as
Cell(1,1): 3 (red color)
Cell(2,1): 2 (green color)
Cell(3,1): 1 (yellow color)

*P/s: I had assigned a macro the insert shapes with specify color (vbRed, vbYellow).

Tried with below coding, no error msg but nth shows.

```
 Sub CalcShape()
     Dim sh As Sheet1
     Dim a As Single
     Dim b As Single
     Dim shp As Shape
     Dim vbYellow As Long
     Dim vbGrey As Long
     Dim vbRed As Long
     Dim vbGreen As Long

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each shp In sh.Shapes
            If shp.Type = ShapeType Then
                If Shapes.Fill.ForeColor = vbRed Then
                   Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) = Shapes.Count

                End If
            End If
        Next

        For Each shp In sh.Shapes
            If shp.Type = ShapeType Then
                If Shapes.Fill.ForeColor = vbGreen Then
                    b = a + 1
                    Sheet1.Cells(3, 1) = b

                End If
            End If
        Next    
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not counting your `shp`:

```
For Each shp In sh.Shapes
            If shp.Type = ShapeType Then
                If Shapes.Fill.ForeColor = vbGreen Then
                    b = a + 1
                    Sheet1.Cells(3, 1) = b
                End If
            End If
 Next
```

Here:

```
If Shapes.Fill.ForeColor
```

should be

```
If shp.Fill.ForeColor
```

---

On a different note, you might instead want to consider using `Select Case` for this. Also turn on `Option Explicit` to see what other errors pop up.